# Android : replacing characters in a string

Tags: android, string, replaceall

In my phonebook on my mobile I have all sorts of contacts like :

```
+(353) 085 123 45 67
00661234567
0871234567
(045)123456
```

I'm putting them all into E.164 format which I've largely completed but the question I need resolved is this:

How can I strip all characters (including spaces) except numbers in my string, apart from the first character if it is '+' or a number ?

```
string phoneNumberofContact;
```

So for example the cases above would look like :

```
+3530851234567
00661234567
0871234567
045123456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

To handle `+` only in the first position, you could do:

```
boolean starsWithPlus = input.charAt(0) == '+';
String sanitized = input.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

if (startsWithPlus) {
    sanitized = "+" + sanitized;
}
```

So basically I'm checking to see if it starts with plus, then stripping out everything but digits, and then re-adding the plus if it was there.

### Original

Assuming you only want to keep `+` or digits, a simple regex will work, and `String` provides the `replaceAll()` method to make it even easier.

```
String sanitized = input.replaceAll("[^+0-9]", "");
```

Comment: But how would deal with the first character?

Comment: Do you have `+` characters other than at the start of the string?

Comment: It could be. + is a symbol on the numeric keypad.

Comment: @CHarris I updated my answer to handle this case. If you need to handle keeping the + if it's not the first character but is the first character that is a + or a digit, you could run my original sanitization regex first, then my updated code.

Answer (score 1):

This method would do the trick

```
public String cleanPhoneDigits(String phonenum) {
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
if (phonenum.charAt(0).equals('+') {
     builder.append('+');
}
for (int i = 1; i < phonenum.length(); i++) {
    char c = phonenum.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        builder.append(c);
    }
}
return builder.toString();
}
```